# run install script when installing preference pane

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I've written a ruby script that I am now looking at wrapping up in a preference pane for the purpose of configuring my ruby script. Now I was hoping that there would be a way for me to run some arbitrary commands when this preference pane gets installed in order to install necessary ruby gems etc, however I can't seem to find any documentation on this sort of functionality anywhere.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Cheers
Nick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just call a ruby script that performs any necessary configurations for you.  If you need it to install gems, you'll probably need to run it with elevated privileges.  This is how I've done it in the past:

```
// Get the path to the helper script from the main app bundle
NSBundle *appBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSString *scriptPath = [appBundle pathForResource: @"helperScript" 
                                           ofType: @"rb"];

// Construct the applescript command to run to helper script with elevated privileges
NSString *scriptCommand = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"do shell script \"ruby '%@'\" with administrator privileges", scriptPath];

// Execute the helper script via Applescript, log any errors
NSAppleScript *executeRubyScript = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource: scriptCommand];
NSDictionary *error = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
[executeRubyScript executeAndReturnError: &error];
[executeRubyScript release];
```

Comment: hi lotts, thanks for the response. That seems like a great way to do it. The one bit that I guess I can't get my head around though is whereabouts I put this in my preference pane so that it will be run when the preference pane is installed or run for the first time? Is this even possible or do I just need to write my install script so that it can detect was has already been performed?

Comment: Just make the execution of the script conditional based on what it's supposed to do.  If your script is supposed to put files in a certain location, check to see if the files exist before running the script.